# How can I try the root on ZFS feature in the eoan desktop installer?

Tags: zfs

I've been excited about the root on ZFS feature that's been announced for eoan, but I don't see how to enable the option in the installer.

I have downloaded and tried a couple of the daily desktop images.
Is it ready yet?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Eoan is [in feature freeze](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2019-August/001263.html), so there is an argument to be made that this is actually on-topic [under our actual policy](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate). I *have* voted to close this (it seems to ask *if* a particular feature is usable yet, and seems like it may be a question about a problem with recent daily live images). But if you believe it's on-topic then I recommend editing and/or commenting to clarify that, and maybe also editing with more details.

Comment: Well...the public reports talk about how it's an "experimental" feature; looking at the requirements for curtin and ubiquity (and their most recent release dates), it seems that maybe the feature from the installer standpoint didn't make feature freeze.  But in looking I couldn't find a path to activating it, in the dailies for either server or desktop.   I don't know if this represents a problem or the desired state of eoan for release, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Installer support has been merged:  http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/ubiquity/ubiquity_19.10.14/changelog

So the ZFS install option should show up in the eoan daily desktop images starting on 10/6/2019.

According to the documentation, the option to install on ZFS should show up when the "Expert Mode" flag is enabled (F6 on the installer screen, before the installer starts, and then check "Expert Mode".